# Thread dump: What is the meaning of parking to wait for?

Tags: java, multithreading

In my application thread dump, most of the threads are waiting on some hexa string 0x00000000ab0eaae8.

**Example**
parking to wait for  **<0x00000000ab0eaae8>** (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)

How can I know, on what my threads are waiting for?

Complete thread stack trace is given below.

```
"qtp685934-2328" #2328 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000023b6000 nid=0x2f1f waiting on condition [0x00007f6df703f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000ab0eaae8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at org.apache.http.pool.AbstractConnPool.getPoolEntryBlocking(AbstractConnPool.java:380)
    at org.apache.http.pool.AbstractConnPool.access$200(AbstractConnPool.java:69)
    at org.apache.http.pool.AbstractConnPool$2.get(AbstractConnPool.java:246)
    - locked <0x00000000e728c1e8> (a org.apache.http.pool.AbstractConnPool$2)
    at org.apache.http.pool.AbstractConnPool$2.get(AbstractConnPool.java:193)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.leaseConnection(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:303)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager$1.get(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:279)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:191)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.java:87)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:723)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:680)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:600)
```

Comment: This is funtionality in the PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager. These threads are in a thread pool waiting for jobs.

Comment: Thanks, what meant by waiting on condition?

Comment: It means when that when a new request comes into your spring server, it will pass off this connection to the thread pool, which will had it off it a waiting thread or if all threads are busy will put it on  queue to be available for the next available free thread.